# How can I let user input a value not listed in a pull-down list?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms

This is really a "best practices" question: Assume I have a dynamically generated pull-down list populated with suggested values (e.g. [Vanilla, Strawberry, Chocolate]).  How do I give the user the option of selecting one of the suggested values OR inputting a new value (e.g. "Rocky Road")?

One approach would be to populate the list with a None of the Above entry ([Vanilla, Strawberry, Chocolate, None of the Above]) and write my controller so that if None of the Above is selected, it will then render a form with a text field instead of the pull-down.  But that feels horribly clunky.

Is there some elegant GUI technique for this sort of thing, perhaps using JQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use simple text input with jquery autocomplate plugin don't use pull-down list. Autocomplate can work with datas you populated. If user inputs a new value, in controller use find_or_create_by dynamic activerecord method.

Comment: This sounds right to me.  Is there only one autocomplete plugin?  If there is more than one, how do I find the most widely supported plugin?

Comment: The rails3-jquery-autocomplate gem is right for you. You can check at github page https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete